# Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Seems running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.

```
linux Firefox -v report:Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/user/.Xauthority which is owned by user)
```

Any comments/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You saw it right.

In the discussion [Cannot run Firefox as root](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460297) *Daniel Veditz* in his [comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460297#c1) clearly mentioned:

> There is no recommended way to run Firefox as root, and because of our sandboxing techniques it's quite broken even if we hadn't explicitly disabled it through start-up checks. As a "bug" this is not something we're going to fix.

They further added,

> "Run Firefox as root" doesn't seem to be your ultimate intention though, more like "How do I manage a shared Firefox installation so it gets updates?" That sounds like a support question rather than a bug. I don't actually know that answer--I don't use a shared machine or multiple accounts so I just install locally--but you can try our support site https://support.mozilla.org/ or our forums https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/forums/ or maybe even StackOverflow once more people run into this issue.

This issue was marked with status as ***RESOLVED WONTFIX***

---

### tl; dr

[tell us Firefox unsupported in Linux root](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1206441)